# How to fit image on canvas without loosing quality of image

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am drawing image on canvas.But image it displaying image on center.But i want to fit the images on entire canvas without scale the image.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 
                 (BaseActivity.width / 2) - mBitmap.getWidth()/2, 
                 (BaseActivity.height / 2) - mBitmap.getHeight()/2,
                 mPaint);

        canvas.restore();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setTextSize(12.0f);

    }
```

If anyone have idea.Please reply.Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use  canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);

Comment: thaks for reply @piyus gupta.Already use this method image is drawing on top in canvas.

Comment: But when using your code it display always in center

Comment: Yes,Right.I am trying your answered code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are extending View class... 
use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to get corresponding dimensions and draw the Bitmap...

```
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Rect imageRect;


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(imageRect == null) { // I think it is always false as we are intializing it onSizeChanged
            imageRect = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, imageRect, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        imageRect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Gopal, It displaying poor quality of images.

Comment: Can we display the image actual size on canvas?

Comment: How can you display a small Image on 70 mm screen without blurring or poor quality? obviously your image will be poor when you zoom it...

Comment: and to Draw actual size image, use `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);`

Comment: Is there any idea,just we can display the actual image means same width as image on canvas.

Comment: Yes,I am trying it.reply you asap.